# Multiple file operations in Tridion limited by six

Tags: core-service, cme, event-system

In Tridion multiple operations involving more than six files are failing. Some sample operations are shown below.

- Delete more than `6` users
- Delete more than '6' TBB
- Move more than 6 building block components or structure groups.

All operations are limited by the number 6. Has anyone faced this issue. Any solutions/suggestions.?

Below error is shown for failed operations

`MultipleOperations.svc/MultipleCopyPaste failed to execute. STATUS (500): System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException`

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the errors you're getting? Do you have any code to share? Surely your Tridion is not jinxed. ;)

Comment: Not jinxed :).. this happens in one environment only. We have Dev and Test environment. this issue occurs only in Test.. that reoccurs for Deletion of more than 6 items.. it goes on fro sometime and time out error is show. I checked to see if it is Database connectivity issue. All other are functioning but this only is not working

Comment: Is this in the CME? (i.e., you select multiple items and then select a task?) Or programatically (as suggested by the core-service tag)?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the box? Could be just a one-off glitch.  Also, is your test CM in a different firewall segment than the CM DB? Timeout errors could suggest packets aren't going through.

Comment: When you say "failing", that doesn't help much. (Ever get a bug report with "X doesn't work!!!"?) In order for anyone to offer any insights into this, you first need to go and dig in the logs and find out what actually happened.

Comment: Yes I tried rebooting the box. 
The exact error getting for multiple operation is 
.
`/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/MultipleOperations.svc/MultipleCopyPaste failed to execute. STATUS (500): System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException`

Comment: @b00tbu9: your Windows event log should contain additional information about that `ServiceActivationException`. Please look up the full error message there and add it to *your original question*.

Comment: Below link helped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you might want to take a look at Dominic's post here : http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/tridion-explorer-reports-system.servicemodel.serviceactivationexception and try the web.config settings he describes as a test?